# If $T:V \to W$ is a linear transformation such that $T^2 = 0$, then $Im(T) \subseteq Ker(T)$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Is it true or false that if $V$ is a vector space and $T:V \to W$ is a linear transformation such that $T^2 = 0$, then $Im(T) \subseteq Ker(T)$ ?
I don't understand it that much. It doesn't seem related... I can have a vector $v$ from $V$ that its power by 2 equals zero but $T(v) \neq 0_{v}$

Comment: NB that $T^2$ only makes sense if $W \subseteq V$. Did you mean, e.g., a transformation $T: V \to V$?

Answer (score 3):

Follow the definitions:

Assume $T^2=0$, this means that for every $v \in V$, $T\circ T(v)=0$, or by definition of the image of $T$, for every $w \in \text{Im}(T)$, $T(w)=0$. therefore the claim

Answer (score 3):

Let $v\in Im(T)$. Therefore, exists $u\in V$, such that $T(u)=v$. But, $T^2(u)=0$, and this is also $T(v)=T(T(u))=T^2(u)=0$, and therefore, $v\in Ker(T)$, and therefore, $Im(T)\subseteq Ker(T)$.